# Array value post-increment

Tags: java, arrays, increment

I've been working on a few array examples. with some success along alone the way. I've been working on this code for the pass few days and just cant understand the purpose of this increment in the loop body. it usually makes since when it is isolated but this time i have no idea what it does.

**Count the occurrences of integers between 1 and 10**

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int[] count = new int[10];

System.out.println("Enter the integers between 1 and 10: ");

// Read all numbers
// 2 5 6 5 4 3 9 7 2 0
for (int i = 0; i < count.length; i++)
{
    int number = input.nextInt();
    count[number]++; //this is the one that perplexes me the most
}

//Display result
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
{
    if (count[i] > 0) 
    {
        System.out.println(i + " occurs " + count[i]
                + ((count[i] == 1) ? " time" : " times"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Does this remark ".. this time i have no idea what it does .." also mean you do not know what programming language you are using? If you do, please [edit] your question and at the very least add a tag for it. And as long as you are doing that, why not read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try to improve it a bit.

Comment: `count[number]++; //this is the one that perplexes me the most` – what’s perplexing about that? There is an array named `count`, and for each number that was input by the user, the according array element is incremented by one – so that in the end that array can tell, how many times each single number was entered by the user.

Comment: You see when i see code like this count[number]++; i usually think adding a number to an index in the sense that it moves it forward and not the way you explained it.

Comment: Why manually enter the integers between 1 and 10 when you could just do a for-loop to add the 10 integers to the array? I think that string should read "Enter 10 integers" because that is what the code is actually doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
count[number]++; //this is the one that perplexes me the most
```

It increments the value in the array `count` at index `number`. Perhaps, splitting it may help understand:

```
int tmp = count[number];
tmp = tmp + 1;
count[number] = tmp;
```

i.e. The value of `count[number]` will be incremented *after* the execution of the the statement `count[number]++;`.

---

Also a note on how post-increment works.

If it were used as:

```
int value = count[number]++;
```

then `value` will have the old value at `count[number]` and the increment will be done *after* the execution of the statement.

Comment: It has been a while since I've been here and I now can see how simple the answer was to the problem. Thanks for the help everyone.